# Lookup list of Maps variable in data weave script

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have a list of maps (listOfMapsObject) like below

```
[
 {
  "Id" : "1234",
  "Value" : "Text1"
  },
  {
  "Id" : "1235",
  "Value" : "Text2"
  }
]
```

I would like access "Value" field for a given Id in dataweave script.
For example: For Id = 1234, Text1 should be returned.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%var listOfMapsObject = flowVars.listOfMaps
---
payload map {
    "key" : $.key,
    "data" : lookup Value field in listOfMapsObject by given key 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Approch suggested by @'sulthony h' is fine but it will end up in performance issue if you large number of data in  pyload and listOfMapsObject. As filter is used , for each record of payload script will loop for all the entries in flowVars.listOfMaps.

Following will work fine and map key value only once.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json 
%var dataLookup = {(flowVars.listOfMaps map {
        ($.Id): $.Value
     })}
---
payload map {
    key : $.key,
    data : dataLookup[$.key]
}
```

Output-

```
[
  {
    "key": "1234",
    "data": "Text1"
  },
  {
    "key": "1235",
    "data": "Text2"
  }
]
```

Where Payload -

```
[
 {
  "key" : "1234" 
  },
  {
  "key" : "1235"
  }
]
```

And -

```
[
 {
  "Id" : "1234",
  "Value" : "Text1"
  },
  {
  "Id" : "1235",
  "Value" : "Text2"
  }
]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: if i hardcode the $.key value  example: dataLookup["1234"], then the value is returned but for dataLookup[$.key] its returning null. What could be the issue?

Comment: Which version of dataweave used. It works fine with 3.8.1

Answer (score 0):

I create my own object with the slightly similar object and successfully access "value" field with the following DataWeave expression:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%var listOfMapsObject = flowVars.listOfMaps
---
payload map using(data = $) {
    "key" : data.key,
    "data" : (listOfMapsObject filter $.id == data.key).value reduce ($$ ++ $)
}
```

You can modify it with your own object, e.g.: replace the "id" with "Id". Test and evaluate the result by using `filter`, `flatten`, `reduce`, etc.

Comment: How can i avoid  repeating (listOfMapsObject filter $.id == data.key) if we want value1 , value2 ?                                                                            payload map using(data = $)  {
    "key" : data.key,
    "data1" : (listOfMapsObject filter $.id == data.key).value1 reduce ($$ ++ $),"data2" : (listOfMapsObject filter $.id == data.key).value2 reduce ($$ ++ $) }