# Combine records into a single JSON object per Category using Dataweave

Tags: mule, aggregate, flatten, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I am using Anypoint Studio 6.1 and Mule 3.8.1 and in Dataweave I have a CSV file as input and JSON list output.

Multiple records are coming in on the CSV file with the same Product Category Id but will have a different product details associated with it.  I want my output to be aggregated for each of these records so I have one object for each Product Category Id which contains a list of the product details for each product under that Product Category id.  How can I do this?

**Current output:**

```
[
  {
    "Products": {
      "ProductDetails": [
        {
          "ProductDetail": {
            "ProductSubDetails": {
              "ProductAmount": 7.50,
              "ProductReplenFrequency": "monthly",
              "ProductsNotes": "Product Notes 1",
              "pick": false
            },
            "ProductType": "PS4 Game"
          },
          "ProductSubType": "Game"
        }
      ]
    },
    "ProductsCategoryId": "ProductS001",
    "ProductSubType": "Computers and Games"
  },
  {
    "Products": {
      "ProductDetails": [
        {
          "ProductDetail": {
            "ProductSubDetails": {
              "ProductAmount": 7.50,
              "ProductReplenFrequency": "fortnightly",
              "ProductsNotes": "Products Notes 2",
              "pick": false
            },
            "ProductType": "X Box One Game"
          },
          "ProductSubType": "Game"
        }
      ]
    },
    "ProductsCategoryId": "ProductS001",
    "ProductSubType": "Computers and Games"
  }
]
```

**Expected output:**

```
[
  {
    "Products": {
      "ProductDetails": [
        {
          "ProductDetail": {
            "ProductSubDetails": {
              "ProductAmount": 7.50,
              "ProductReplenFrequency": "monthly",
              "ProductsNotes": "Product Notes 1",
              "pick": false
            },
            "ProductType": "PS4 Game"
          },
          "ProductSubType": "Game"
        },
        {
          "ProductDetail": {
            "ProductSubDetails": {
              "ProductAmount": 7.50,
              "ProductReplenFrequency": "fortnightly",
              "ProductsNotes": "Products Notes 2",
              "pick": false
            },
            "ProductType": "X Box One Game"
          },
          "ProductSubType": "Game"
        }       
      ]
    },
    "ProductsIdentifier": "ProductS001",
    "ProductSubType": "Computers and Games"
  }
]
```

**Dataweave code:**

```
%dw 1.0
%input payload application/csv
%output application/json skipNullOn = "everywhere" , encoding = "UTF-8"
%var dataLookup = {(payload."ProductsCategoryId" map {($.Id): $.Value})}

---
(payload filter $$ > 2) map ((payload01 , indexOfPayload01) -> {
    Products: {
        ProductsDetails: [{
            ProductsDetail: {
                ProductsubDetails: {
                    ProductsAmount: payload01."Products Amount" as :number,
                    ProductsFrequency: payload01."Products Frequency"
                },
                ProductsType: payload01."Products Type"
            }
        }]
    },
    ProductsCategoryId: payload01."ProductsCategoryId"
})
```

**Sample Data:**

```
ProductsCategoryId,Product Type,Product  Frequency,Product Amount
ProductS001,PS4 Game,Monthly,7.5
ProductS001,X Box One Game,Fortnightly,7.5
ProductS002,Lego,Daily,7
```

Thanks

Comment: Would you mind providing some sample input as well?

Comment: I've added sample csv data with 2 records with the same Products Category Id.  I have been looking at group by and flatten commands but not been able to get the right result.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use look up for achieving desired output. Please refer the following answer for more details

[Lookup list of Maps variable in data weave script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39301428/lookup-list-of-maps-variable-in-data-weave-script/39310534#39310534)

Updated answer as per comments

Try with following mapping. Also I am not sure why you have use filter $$ > 2.
For body starts at line 5 you can add input reader property "bodyStartLineNumber" Please refer [link](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-formats#reader-properties) for more details

```
%dw 1.0
%input payload application/csv
%output application/json skipNullOn = "everywhere" , encoding = "UTF-8"
---
payload groupBy $.ProductsCategoryId map {
    Products: {
        ProductsDetails:   $ map (product , indexOfProduct) -> {
            ProductsDetail: {
                ProductsubDetails: {
                    ProductsAmount: product."Product Amount" as :number,
                    ProductsFrequency: product."Product Frequency"
                },
                ProductsType: product."Product Type"
            }
        }
    },
    ProductsCategoryId: $."ProductsCategoryId"[0]
}
```

Output gnerated:-

```
[
  {
    "Products": {
      "ProductsDetails": [
        {
          "ProductsDetail": {
            "ProductsubDetails": {
              "ProductsAmount": 7
            },
            "ProductsType": "Lego"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "ProductsCategoryId": "ProductS002"
  },
  {
    "Products": {
      "ProductsDetails": [
        {
          "ProductsDetail": {
            "ProductsubDetails": {
              "ProductsAmount": 7.5
            },
            "ProductsType": "PS4 Game"
          }
        },
        {
          "ProductsDetail": {
            "ProductsubDetails": {
              "ProductsAmount": 7.5
            },
            "ProductsType": "X Box One Game"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "ProductsCategoryId": "ProductS001"
  }
]
```

HTH

Comment: I'm seeing an error with the solution when I try to use the dataLookup function which is "Cannot coerce a :null to a :key".  I have updated the code in the question and csv file to a smaller number of fields.  Do you know could be causing this and how I could ignore nulls?  One thing to note is that the body starts at line 5 in the CSV file.

Comment: Also, is there any documentation around dataLookup function.  Struggling to find any to help look into this issue